# How to pass multiple function in raster::extract()

Tags: r, parallel-processing, extract

I'm working with a raster CHM and I've to extract several metrics from a polygon shapefile. Now I'm doing something like this:

```
library(raster)
library(sp)

#from the help page of extract
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, vals=1:(18*36))
cds1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-160,5), c(-60, 0), c(-160,-60), c(-180,-20))
cds2 <- rbind(c(80,0), c(100,60), c(120,0), c(120,-55), c(80,0))
polys <- spPolygons(cds1, cds2)

#metrics extraction
mean <- extract(r, polys,mean,df=T)
min<-extract(r, polys,min,df=T)
max<-extract(r, polys,max,df=T)
#and so on for other summary functions (like sd, mode, median, sum etc...)
```

I would know if there is a way to pass all the summary functions to the fun= argument of the extract() function and if it's possible to do it in parallel.
Thanks for every help.

N.B. this is my first question in StackOverflow, I apologize for any impropriety

Comment: Perhaps neater would be to write a function that calls each of these extract calls and returns a list of all of the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dww suggests above in the comments, here is a function which calculates a number of summary statistics and returns them as a vector. It is passed to the `fun` argument of `raster::extract`. Note that the documentation from `raster::extract` says that the function must accept a `na.rm` argument. I was unable to change the default behavior of `extract` for naming the columns of the data frame output so I manually set the names afterward.

## Code

```
my_summary <- function(x, na.rm) c(mean = mean(x, na.rm=na.rm), min = min(x, na.rm=na.rm), max = max(x, na.rm=na.rm))
r_summary <- extract(r, polys, fun = my_summary, df = TRUE)
names(r_summary) <- c('ID', 'mean', 'min', 'max')
```

## Output

```
  ID     mean min max
1  1 387.8158 326 507
2  2 321.0800 172 498
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wandering if the option of running multiple functions in a single extract call was faster and indeed is.

Below is the example from [Elia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10782674/elia) and the answer from [qdread](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2854608/qdread) using the `terra` package and a `microbenchmark` evaluation. The second option is almost three times faster:

```
library(terra)
library(microbenchmark)
# library(sp)

#from the help page of extract
r <- rast(ncol=36, nrow=18, vals=1:(18*36))
cds1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-160,5), c(-60, 0), c(-160,-60), c(-180,-20))
cds2 <- rbind(c(80,0), c(100,60), c(120,0), c(120,-55), c(80,0))
polys <- terra::vect(rbind(cds1, cds2), type="polygons")

#metrics extraction
microbenchmark(A={
mean <- extract(r, polys,mean,df=T)
min<-extract(r, polys,min,df=T)
max<-extract(r, polys,max,df=T)
#and so on for other summary functions (like sd, mode, median, sum etc...)
},
B={
my_summary <- function(x, na.rm = T) c(mean = mean(x, na.rm=na.rm), min = min(x, na.rm=na.rm), max = max(x, na.rm=na.rm))
r_summary <- extract(r, polys, fun = my_summary)
names(r_summary) <- c('ID', 'mean', 'min', 'max')
})
```

Evaluation:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval cld
    A 5.8892 5.98180 6.429374 6.12040 6.25440 19.2841   100   b
    B 2.1281 2.16045 2.357640 2.18765 2.30115 14.4645   100  a
```

Answer (score 0):

Some years have passed since this question, and I think it could be helpfull to expand a bit on the answer of @Gerald.
At the time of writing, the best solution so far is the `exact_extract` function in the `exactextractr` package. The function can accept as `fun` argument a character vector of functions. `exact_extract` take into account the fraction of the area of each cell that is covered by the polygons, and it is optimized to work with `sf` object and big `SpatRaster` object, as well `Raster*`object.

Here an example and the scalability with a bigger raster than the original example

```
sf_polys <- sf::st_as_sf(polys)
r_summary <- exact_extract(r,sf_polys,fun=c("mean","min","max"))
```

a benchmark with a bigger raster:

```
r <- rast(ncol=3600, nrow=1800, vals=1:(1800*3600))
cds1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-160,5), c(-60, 0), c(-160,-60), c(-180,-20))
cds2 <- rbind(c(80,0), c(100,60), c(120,0), c(120,-55), c(80,0))

microbenchmark(A = {
  mean <- extract(r, polys, mean, df = T)
  min <- extract(r, polys, min, df = T)
  max <- extract(r, polys, max, df = T)
  #and so on for other summary functions (like sd, mode, median, sum etc...)
},
B = {
  my_summary <-
    function(x, na.rm = T)
      c(
        mean = mean(x, na.rm = na.rm),
        min = min(x, na.rm = na.rm),
        max = max(x, na.rm = na.rm)
      )
  r_summary <- extract(r, polys, fun = my_summary)
  names(r_summary) <- c('ID', 'mean', 'min', 'max')
},
C = {
  r_summary <- exact_extract(r, sf_polys, fun = c('mean', 'min', 'max'))
})
```

here the results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval cld
    A 6309.1327 6362.1017 6489.0986 6459.2223 6632.241 6710.0625    100   c
    B 2100.8945 2116.3198 2156.2030 2137.7992 2162.850 2283.2969    100  b 
    C  130.3108  146.3663  184.8943  151.0666  157.701  505.5154    100 a
```

As it can be seen, the C approach is way faster than the other two